# Processdialog just doesn't show up

Tags: android, dictionary, progressdialog

In my android application, I have written a async task which fetches geo location data from google app engine datastore.All works fine, except that process dialog doesn't show no matter what I do. I have followed all available tutorials etc but of no avail.

Here is what I do:

I have an activity to show map data.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity....

//On click of a button OR when user location changes, following method is called:

    private void findAction(Location location){

        //this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        FetchHospitalsAsyncTask asyncTask = new FetchHospitalsAsyncTask(this);
        List<Hospital> nearByHospitals = null;
        try {
            nearByHospitals = asyncTask.execute(1000.0, latitude, longitude).get();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

...and here is my async class

```
public class FetchHospitalsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, List<Hospital>> {
    private static String TAG = FetchHospitalsAsyncTask.class.getName();
    private static HospitalApi hospitalApiService = null;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private Activity parentActivity = null;


    public FetchHospitalsAsyncTask(Activity parentActivity){
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(parentActivity);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.Fetching data from server....");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Hospital> result){
        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Hospital> doInBackground(Double... params) {
        /*
        */

        /*context = params[0].first;
        String name = params[0].second;
        String address= params[1].second;*/
        double radius = params[0];
        double lat = params[1];
        double lon = params[2];

        try {
            com.cypherlabs.mumbaihospitalfinder.backend.hospitalApi.HospitalApi.GetNearByHospitals nearByHospitals=hospitalApiService.getNearByHospitals(radius,lat,lon);
            nearByHospitals.getLastStatusCode();
            return nearByHospitals.execute().getItems();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //return e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Process dialog shows no trace whatsoever of its existence, while all other things work fine.Map is rendered with all markers etc.

Comment: remove `.get();` its not needed

Comment: ....sorr for typo.Process dialog means Progress dialog.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29. it waits for the result making asynctask no more asynchronous. remove `get()`

Comment: Hi Raghu, server data is fetched correctly. Its progress dialog which is not showing up.

Comment: read the link i posted.

Comment: @user2444661: Remove `.get()` then progress dialog will show

Comment: Hi ,thanks for reply. How do I then receive data returned by async task.

Comment: @user2444661: In `onPostExecute` method receive all data

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. I made all the suggested changes, and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.get()` on the AsyncTask. This will cause the AsyncTask to run synchronously instead of asynchronously. This causes the UI thread to be blocked and as such the progress dialogue will not show.

You need to call `execute()` on the AsyncTask instead. This will cause the AsyncTask to run in a separate thread and not block the UI. Note that the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods will be run on the same thread you called `execute` from

Answer (score 0):

Using get() means it will freezes your main ui thread untill the Async task is finished. Adding a progress dialog will run on main Ui thread. And as you are using get() it will not allow any changes to main ui. So remove get() you will get progress dialog works.